# URL parcial + Uri.parse

Tags: android

Me encuentro ante un problema tratando de agregar una URL parcial + un dominio o URL generado por un EditText , dejo un ejemplo del código haber si alguno podría decirme donde esta el error, ya que no encuentro solución por ningún medio.

Codigo:

```
Uri uriUrl = "http://google"+Uri.parse(et1.getText().toString());
Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
```

Asi tenia entendido que se escribia probe de mil maneras pero no logro encontrar el modo correcto

Comment: El problema es que tienes que convertir todo tu url que es un String a Uri, agregue respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que tienes que convertir todo tu url que es un String a [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html), mediante `Uri.parse()` :

```
Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://google"+et1.getText().toString());
```

de esta forma usarlo en el Intent:

```
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
startActivity(launchBrowser);
```

Esta es otra opción:

```
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google"+et1.getText().toString()));
startActivity(launchBrowser);
```

---

Asegura revisar que la url que intentas convertir a [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html), en realidad sea valida:

```
String miUrl = "http://google"+et1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Gracias en verdad por corregir la línea

Answer (score 1):

En esta linea estas intentando hacer un `Uri.parse` a solo un texto que puede ser `.com`, `.es`, `.cl`, etc etc.

Lo que te recomiendo es que antes de intentar hacer eso, verifiques si lo que tiene el `EditText` es una URL. Tambien lo que podrias hacer es definir un `array` con los dominios que pretendes aceptar.

```
String[] dominios = { ".com", ".es", ".cl", ".pe"};
if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(et1.getText().toString()){
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(et1.getText().toString()));
    startActivity(intent);
}else{
    //Si no es una URL formas la que tienes de ejemplo
    if (Arrays.asList(dominios).contains(et1.getText().toString())) {
       Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://www.google"+et1.getText().toString());
       Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
       startActivity(intent);
    }else{
       //Error el dominio ingresado no esta.
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias como siempre, agregué en mi código la parte que valida lo que se escribe en el EditText y con la respuesta de Elenasys logre lo que quería